# (PyQt5) Is there any way to call the method 'setUrl' (QWebEngineView object) through a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, asyncore

I'm trying to call a method, QWebEngineView - 'setUrl' through a thread. 
But it shows me an windows error(Application has stopped working).

ex) QWebEngineView side

```
class Main_UI(QWidget):
   ....
   self.web_view = QWebEngineView(self)
   ....

main_ui = Main_UI()
```

ex) Thread side (using asyncore)

```
class CustomThread(asyncore.dispatcher):
  ...
  main_ui.web_view.setUrl(QUrl("example.com"))
  ...
```

when the thread calls main_ui - web_view.setUrl, 
it shows me an windows error.

thanks for reading this and I hope get good solution.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: You have to use signals to be able to transfer information from a thread since the GUI can not be updated from another thread that is not the main thread.

Comment: the error is "Application has stopped working" windows message.

Comment: I'm trying to use signal. but it shows me 'signal only works in main thread'. So I have to research into it more deeply. thank you to reply.